# QLIKVIEW 11: Formula works on Text Object but not in LOAD SCRIPT

Tags: qlikview, set-analysis

I have the following formula in a Text Object:

```
=Num(Sum(Aggr(Count({<Jahr={$(vTodayYear)}, Kw={">=1<=$(vTodayKw)"}, Database.Kennzahl={'Ew'}, Database.Szenario={'Actual'}>} DISTINCT Database.MitarbeiterID), Kw) /  vTodayKw) , '###.##0')
```

This works and it gives me the desired Value. But when I want to SET it to LOAD SCRIPT like this:

```
SET vMyVar = =Num(Sum(Aggr(Count({<Jahr={$(vTodayYear)}, Kw={">=1<=$(vTodayKw)"}, Database.Kennzahl={'Ew'}, Database.Szenario={'Actual'}>} DISTINCT Database.MitarbeiterID), Kw) /  vTodayKw) , '###.##0');
```

This doesn't work and theres no ErrorMessage :(

Thanks for any help!

Comment: how and where `vMyVar` is called/used?

Comment: in a Text Object like so: =$(vMyVar)

Answer (score 0):

there is no support for Set Analysis in a LOAD statement.
You have to rewrite your statement to use it in the LOAD statement.

Something like this (depending all fields are in a table named 'Database'):

```
tmp_Mitarbeiter_tbl:
LOAD Count (Distinct Database.MitarbeiterID) as tmp_Mitarbeiter_count
Resident Database
Where Jahr = $(vTodayYear)
    and Kw >= 1 and Kw <= $(vTodayKw)
    and Database.Kennzahl = 'Ew'
    and Database.Szenario = 'Actual';

LET vMyVar = Peek('tmp_Mitarbeiter_count');

DROP Table tmp_Mitarbeiter_tbl;
```

Best regards,

Tom